# Sometimes View.isHidden and View.removeFromSuperview() do not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, admob

By default, banner ads were made to appear. When watch a video ad once, to set the banner ad to not appear for 24 hours.
There are 4 view controllers that display banner ads in a situation where navigation controller used.

Let's call them A, B, C, D respectively. A is first ViewController and it moves in the order of B, C, D, and can go back to the back button or swipe with D → C → B → A.

Setting so that banner advertisements do not appear after watching video advertisements is done in B. After watching a video ad, most of the banner ads disappear as intended.

However, sometimes there are banner ads in A and B.

**Code to show and delete ads**

```
public class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
  
  public lazy var bannerView: GADBannerView = {
    let banner = GADBannerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    return banner
  }()
  
  let ud = UserDefaults.standard
  
  func confirmRemainFreeAdsTime() {
    let current = Date()
    let reactiveBannerTime = ud.object(forKey: "reactiveBannerTime") as? Date
    if let diffTime = reactiveBannerTime?.timeIntervalSince(current) {
      if diffTime <= 0 {
        ud.set(false, forKey: "removeAds24hours")
      }
    }
  }
    
}

extension BaseViewController: GADBannerViewDelegate {

  func setupBannerViewToTop(height: CGFloat = 50) {
    
    let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: adSize)
    
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      bannerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
      bannerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
    ])
    
    // test Id
    bannerView.adUnitID = Constants.GoogleAds.testUnitId
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    bannerView.delegate = self
  }
  
  func removeBannerView() {
    
    bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
    
  }
```

Originally, only `bannerView.removeFromSuperview()` was used, but there were cases where the banner was still visible, so I added `bannerView.isHidden = true`.

**B-viewController : watch video ads and hide banners**

```
      GADRewardedAd.load(withAdUnitID: Constants.GoogleAds.rewardTestUnitId, request: GADRequest()) { rewardedAd, error in
        if let error = error {
          print("Failed to load rewarded ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        self.rewardedAdGlobal = rewardedAd
        self.rewardedAdGlobal?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        
        if let ad = self.rewardedAdGlobal {
          ad.present(fromRootViewController: self) {
            
            // UTC 기준 시간 실제로 이 시간을 기준으로 계산이 이루어진다.
            let reactiveBannerDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 1)
            self.ud.set(reactiveBannerDate, forKey: "reactiveBannerTime")
            
            // 표현되는 현지 시간. VIEW 에 표현되는데 이용된다.
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
            formatter.dateFormat = "[ yyyy-MM-dd a hh:mm ]"
            let dateString = formatter.string(from: reactiveBannerDate)
            self.ud.set(dateString, forKey: "dateString")
            self.ud.set(true, forKey: "removeAds24hours")
            self.removeBannerView()
            
          }
        } else {
        }
      }
```

For testing purposes, the time is set to 1 minute instead of 24 hours.

**B-viewController: viewWillDisappear & viewWillAppear**

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    removeBannerView()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    confirmRemainFreeAdsTime()
    
    let removeBanner = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "removeAds24hours") as? Bool ?? false
    
    if removeBanner {
      removeBannerView()
      let dateString = ud.object(forKey: "dateString") as? String ?? ""
      let nobannerUntil: String = NSLocalizedString("noBannerUntil", comment: "")
      self.removeAdsBtn.setTitle("\(nobannerUntil) \(dateString)" , for: .normal)
      self.removeAdsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: "MiddleYellow") ?? .black, for: .normal)
    } else {
      setupBannerViewToTop()
    }
  }
```

**A-viewController: viewWillDisappear & viewWillAppear**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    removeBannerView()
  }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    confirmRemainFreeAdsTime()

    let removeBanner = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "removeAds24hours") as? Bool ?? false
    
    if !removeBanner {
      setupBannerViewToTop()
    } else {
      removeBannerView()
    }
}
```

set the banner ad to disappear in B and move to C and D, viewDidLoad is called first, and it always succeeds in making the banner ad invisible.

When closes the video ad screen, B's viewWillAppear is called first. viewDidLoad is not called. And sometimes the banner ads disappear and sometimes they don't.

If B goes to A while the banner is still there and returns to B, B's viewDidLoad is called first and the banner advertisement disappears.

In case A, the banner ad disappears or appears as it is. As A is the starting view controller, ViewDidLoad is never called again unless the app is forcibly terminated and the app is started again. So in A, the banner does not disappear, but remains.

I understand that ViewDidLoad must be called to make the banner ad disappear. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit incompatible

```
func removeBannerView() {
    bannerView.isHidden = true
    if !bannerView.isHidden {
      bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
```

because this code won't be executed

```
bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
```

look

```
func removeBannerView() {                  // bannerView.isHidden = any
    bannerView.isHidden = true             // bannerView.isHidden = true
    if !bannerView.isHidden {              // condition always failing
      bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
```

just

```
func removeBannerView() {
   bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

will be ehought

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
at first I did what you said, but it didn't work. I tried changing the code again as you said.
But in the 7th test, the banner didn't disappear in A-viewController.